# Copy rows using tableadapter doesn't commit changes to disk

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, tableadapter, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm trying to copy missing records from one database to another.  The two databases are old Access mdbs.  I'm using C#, dataset, table adapters, etc.  The destination table object ends up with the correct number of rows but the underlying database is not updated.  What am I missing?  And am I doing roughly the right thing or is there a better, simpler way.  The tables in question do not have indexes so I detect whether the record exists by building a Hashset of what should be the key field in the destination table.

The code is below.  The data sources and so on were created using the wizard in VS 2019.

I've scoured the web but found only lots of examples of how to copy data table objects, nothing about committing the changes to the underlying database.

```
namespace ImportTstatDB
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var srcDataSet = new _TSTAT_SPECDataSetSrc();
            var dstDataSet = new _TSTAT_SPECDataSetDst();
            ImportMissingSpecificationMain(srcDataSet, dstDataSet);
            //ImportMissingResultSets(srcDataSet, dstDataSet);
            dstDataSet.AcceptChanges();
            srcDataSet.RejectChanges();
        }


        private static void ImportMissingSpecificationMain(_TSTAT_SPECDataSetSrc srcDataSet, _TSTAT_SPECDataSetDst dstDataSet)
        {
            var srcTableAdapter = new _TSTAT_SPECDataSetSrcTableAdapters.SpecificationMainTableAdapter();
            srcTableAdapter.Fill(srcDataSet.SpecificationMain);
            var srcTable = srcTableAdapter.GetData();

            var dstTableAdapter = new _TSTAT_SPECDataSetDstTableAdapters.SpecificationMainTableAdapter();
            dstTableAdapter.Fill(dstDataSet.SpecificationMain);
            var dstTable = dstTableAdapter.GetData();

            var transformerIDs = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (var dstRow in dstTable)
            {
                var transformerID = dstRow.TransformerID;
                transformerIDs.Add(transformerID);
            }
            foreach (var srcRow in srcTable)
            {
                var transformerID = srcRow.TransformerID;
                if (!transformerIDs.Contains(transformerID))
                {
                    // Doesn't exist so copy
                    srcRow.SetAdded();
                    dstTable.ImportRow(srcRow);
                }
            }
            dstTable.AcceptChanges();
            dstTableAdapter.Update(dstTable);

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct number of rows but the underlying database is not updated". What needs to be updated? Is this a one-time process just to merge data? Why not just use Access to import/modify records?

Comment: @June7: dstTable contains all the records that were in the original database and those read from the srcTable but the actual Access mdb file never changes.  How would I do this with Access?  I don't want to create SQL INSERT statements because I have quite a few tables to update and it would be tedious to write.

Comment: I have built VBA code that merges db's without INSERT statements but use whatever you are comfortable with.

Comment: @June7 I can't easily do that in Access because the installed version of Access can't open those mdbs, they are too old.  But if you could share the code I'm sure I, and others, would have a use for it in other projects.

Comment: My code is too specific for the data I was dealing with. It would not be a suitable answer for this question. How old are these mdb's? Access97 or older?

Comment: @June7 Not sure exactly how old but I know I can't open them in the version of Access that the company in question has installed.  One day I will get around to extracting the data into an SQL Server instance but it's not practical just now.

Comment: @June7: The DataTableAdapters will connect Access files down to at least _Access 2.0_: `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\database.mdb;User ID=UserName;Jet OLEDB:System database=d:\system.mda`.

Answer (score 0):

This line I meet in my in-line comments:

```
// Do NOT call AcceptChanges here as this would clear property RowState.
```

Thus, try commenting out this line:

```
// dstTable.AcceptChanges();
dstTableAdapter.Update(dstTable);
```

Comment: I think I only added that line after finding out that it wasn't working, but I'll try it anyway.  Have to wait until this evening (CET) because the machine I have to use will be in use until then.